# Overflow y scroll not working when going back to the page in Safari 9

Tags: css, scroll, safari, scrollbar, overflow

Having trouble with a overflow y scroll on this page in safari:

http://www.lizzygee.co.uk/product/classic/

If you go to the details tab and click a link further down the page and go to a different page, when you press the back button to return to the product page again the overflow-y scroll suddenly appears to stop working?

Does anyone know what this issue might be ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem (on mac — iOS works great). It seems like a bug in Safari's bfcache (back and forward cache). I don't really have any good solutions, but you can always force a rerendering of the page:

```
<script>
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1 && !is_chrome;
if (is_safari) {
    window.onpageshow = function(event) {
        if (event.persisted) {
            window.location.reload() 
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add {-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch} to your CSS of the overflowing div it should fix the problem. The side effect is that the div will now keep scrolling if you swipe it like android does naturally.